# truffle with ganache uses "UNKNOWN" network instead of "development"

Tags: solidity, truffle, ganache, ganache-cli, ubuntu

When I run `truffle migrate --reset` and then `truffle networks` I see that the contracts were deployed to a network named UNKNOWN.
I have this configuration:

```
development: {
      host: "127.0.0.1", // Localhost (default: none)
      port: 8545, // Standard Ethereum port (default: none)
      network_id: "*", // Any network (default: none)
    },
```

1_initial_migration.js:

```
const Migrations = artifacts.require("Migrations");

module.exports = function (deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(Migrations);
};
```

2_deploy_contracts.js:

```
const Safehouse = artifacts.require("SafeHouse");

module.exports = function (deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(Safehouse);
};
```

I tried to use `--network development` when migrating but that didn't help.

Before that I ran `ganache-cli -m "some words"`.

How can I make truffle deploy the contracts to the `development` network?

Comment: Can you post output or screenshot of  what happens when you try: truffle migrate --network development

Comment: @Sky Compiling your contracts...
=====================
> Everything is up to date, there is nothing to compile.
Network up to date.

Comment: Try to go into your build/contracts directory (You will see a lot of .json files there with the names of your smartContracts. Delete all of them and then try running  truffle migrate --network development again  (Also, could you post your deployment script? It should be in folder named "migrations")

Comment: @sky I edited the question and added the 1_initial_migration.js and 2_deploy_contracts.js scripts. I deleted the files and ran the migration again, but still I don't see the contract in the development network. You can this print screen: https://pasteboard.co/Ny0kqbuXMp4E.png

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your ganache has a different default port. Try editing your truffle-consing.json like this:

```
    development: {
        host: "127.0.0.1",     // Localhost (default: none)
        port: 7545,            // Standard Ethereum port (default: none)
        network_id: "*",       // Any network (default: none)
    },
```

Then run `truffle migrate --network development` again

It might help to install ganache GUI, but to run it, you need to go into permissions and click on (Allow executing file as program)--> See screenshot under.

[image: GanacheGui]

Comment: It says it can't connect to the networks. Which makes sense because when I run Ganache it says it listens on port 8545.

Comment: Could you try to install Ganache GUI ( ganache with grafic interface) ?? Might be helpful

Comment: I installed it and ran "npm start" but a window wasn't opened, just the terminal said it was listening on port 8545. I ran "truffle develop" and that terminal was listening on port 9545, I changed the .conf to use 9545 and it deployed to a network named "develop" (the name I have in .conf) and I had access to it. I thought I should run "truffle develop" and also Ganache, then deploy to the Ganache network. Does "truffle develop" creates a different network than Ganache and I shouldn't use both?

Comment: Yeah!! Ofc, now I get it. You were using truffle develop vs ganache develop. That is why we had this mix up

Comment: But you do seem do have an issue with using ganache. To open ganache GUI you need to allow the application to run (go in its properties and allow for it to be run as application)

Comment: I saw some YouTube video that said I should clone the code then run "npm install" and "npm start" and the GUI didn't work, but now I downloaded the AppImage file and allowed it to run and it worked. 
So if I use "truffle develop" I don't need Ganache?

Comment: OK the important thing is that I needed to use "truffle console" together with Ganache, and not "truffle develop".

Comment: Yeah, I use ganache + truffle console. Not truffle develop.